# How to access client side content from one ECS container to another ECS container where the docker application is hosted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a design in thought for one of my application using AWS ECS  that is  to deploy the (front end )angular content in one container and docker application(server side) in the other container . I would like to know how I can access the content from one container to the docker application hosted  in the other container Aws ECS

Is that same as docker application how it is accessed?

Note* I converted content  file from zip to war to deploy it in container.

Answer (score 1):

create a volume and attach that volume to the two containers. They both can access the contents in the shared volume

Answer (score 0):

In order to share content between containers, you can use shared volumes, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html).